# Plugin of Maven - Automated test

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, maven

I need to run automated test on Bamboo (Atlassian) but I don't know what plugin of maven use.

The automated test are written in Selenium and Java.

Answer (score 1):

Bamboo is an Atlassian product which offshore companies use for Continuous integration as it is a paid tool. We used it in one of our project, so we will give you idea on how it could be achieved.

In order to configure Maven on Bamboo (Atlassian) you need to follow the following steps:

1. Log into your Bamboo instance as an admin and then select Add-ons.
2. Now, click on Find new add-ons from the left-hand side of the page and locate Maven POM Value Extractor via search.
3. Results include add-on versions compatible with your Bamboo instance.
4. Now, install your add-on.

Please refer to below links for more details: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.davidehringer.atlassian.bamboo.maven.maven-pom-parser-plugin/server/installation

For configuring Maven job from Bamboo, refer to link provided below: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/maven-289277038.html

Answer (score 0):

With Maven you can use for running the test cases

1. http://maven.apache.org/components/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/
2. http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/

If you use the TestNG as the Test framework, you can run the test by declaring testng.xml file under suiteXmlFiles tag.

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.19.1</version>
   <configuration>
     <suiteXmlFiles>
       <suiteXmlFile>Builds/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
     </suiteXmlFiles>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```